# Java Blackberry sending custom made packet

Tags: sockets, networking, blackberry, java-me

i need to recreate this within Java for Blackberry device:

```
char cPacketData[1024];
int thisPacketLength=( X_PACKET_SPACE*12 ) + ( 20*X_PACKET_SPACE );
(*(int *)   (cPacketData))          =X_PACKET_START;    
(*(int *)   (cPacketData+X_PACKET_SPACE))   =thisPacketLength;  
(*(int *)   (cPacketData+X_PACKET_SPACE*2)) =X_PACKET_POSITION_DATA;    
(*(int *)   (cPacketData+X_PACKET_SPACE*3)) =positionX;
(*(int *)   (cPacketData+X_PACKET_SPACE*4)) =positionY;

send(mSocket,(const char *)&cPacketData,thisPacketLength,0);
```

I already know that i should use

```
OutputStreamWriter
```

but i don't know how to recreate that packet in Java, can you please help?

***UPDATE***
Ok, think i've got it right:

```
char[] payload = new char[100];
int start=9999;
payload[3] = (char)((start >> 24) & 0XFF);
payload[2] = (char)((start >> 16) & 0XFF);
payload[1] = (char)((start >> 8) & 0XFF);
payload[0] = (char)((start >> 0) & 0XFF);

int len=100;
payload[X_PACKET_SPACE+3] = (char)((len >> 24) & 0XFF);
payload[X_PACKET_SPACE+2] = (char)((len >> 16) & 0XFF);
payload[X_PACKET_SPACE+1] = (char)((len >> 8) & 0XFF);
payload[X_PACKET_SPACE]   = (char)((len >> 0) & 0XFF);


_out.write(payload);
```

Seems to work fine, kinda 'oldsKewl' way of doing - so i would appreciate if you guys have any better option.

Just to confirm, it works by doing it this way.

Comment: The C code is using a reinterpret cast, which is something Java explicitly doesn't allow, in order to maintain type safety.  Your bitshifting and masking is what I would expect for this type of network code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved**

Here is how i do it, so that my server side can recv the packets from BB correctly.

```
OutputStream    _out = conn.openOutputStream();

                            packet[3]= (byte)(9999 >>> 24);
                            packet[2]= (byte)(9999 >>> 16);
                            packet[1]= (byte)(9999 >>> 8);
                            packet[0]= (byte)(9999 >>> 0);

                            packet[8]= (byte)(60 >>> 24);
                            packet[7]= (byte)(60 >>> 16);
                            packet[6]= (byte)(60 >>> 8);
                            packet[5]= (byte)(60 >>> 0);

                            packet[13]= (byte)(4 >>> 24);
                            packet[12]= (byte)(4 >>> 16);
                            packet[11]= (byte)(4 >>> 8);
                            packet[10]= (byte)(4 >>> 0);

                            packet[18]= (byte)(_PIN >>> 24);
                            packet[17]= (byte)(_PIN >>> 16);
                            packet[16]= (byte)(_PIN >>> 8);
                            packet[15]= (byte)(_PIN >>> 0);          

                            packet[23]= (byte)(1 >>> 24);
                            packet[22]= (byte)(1 >>> 16);
                            packet[21]= (byte)(1 >>> 8);
                            packet[20]= (byte)(1 >>> 0);                 

_out.write(packet,0,60);
```